# How to solve a " stack corrupted" problem with array in C++ coding

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "please input a string: ";
    char str[50];
    cin >> str[50];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

This is my code. However, no matter how many characters I type in, it will only report to me that "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted."

I was trying to use Visual Studio to write code putting the user's input string into a char array and split it into every char. Then count how many characters, numbers and punctuation marks are in the string.

Comment: `cin >> str[50];` tries to input a single character one past the end of the allocated array. If you can use `std::string` you should.

Comment: It is often a good idea to ask your question **before** posting any code; cf. [ask].

Comment: Change `cin >> str[50]` to `cin >> str`. Also would help if you declare `str` as `std::string`

Comment: This is a fairly common (but rather bizarre) newbie misunderstanding. The error is that thinking that if you have a array called `str` of size 50 (say) then the notation `str[50]` is the way to refer to the whole array. In reality the notation `[n]` is used for two different purposes. In the array declaration it indicates the size of the array, but after that it always indicates that you are *indexing* the array. Since your array has a size of 50, `str[50]` is always going to be an error since the only valid indexes are from 0 to 49.

Comment: You should resist the temptation to make up your own rules about C++. It's a perfectly well designed language but it is absolutely not an intuitive language. If you attempt to guess about how it works, you are likely to go wrong. Really the only way to learn C++ is to study some competent tutorial that explains the rules.

Comment: @john A perfectly well designed language it's not. Very far from it. There are holes, warts, bad design decisions, very bad design decisions, and outright catastrophic design decisions mixed in with some very good parts.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn''t realize how stupid my mistake is until I see your comments! By the way, speaking of competent tutorial, do you have any suggestion?(I just know too little about C++ to use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain what's wrong, I'd like you to look at your loop:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
{
    cout << str[i] << " ";
}
```

`cout << str[i]` accesses a single `char` in your array and prints it.

The very same thing is what you are doing when taking input from the user:

```cpp
cin >> str[50]; // extract a single `char` from `cin` and put it in str[50]
```

However, `str[50]` is out of bounds since arrays are zero-based and only 0-49 are valid. Writing out of bounds makes your program have undefined behavior and a stack corruption is one possible outcome.

If you want to extract a C string, remove the subscript operator:

```
std::cin >> str;
```

Note: Before C++20, a user of the program could still overflow `str` by entering more than 49 `char`s. A better option is usually to use a `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with my problem. After reading your answer I feel so clear!

Comment: @Throwa0112 Glad it helped! You're welcome!